# Is there a way to see the files that I have applied changes from a specific date to now?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Do you know if there is a way to see the files that I have applied changes from a specific date to now?

I mean, I am working on a parent ticket on Jira since August 4th, that parent ticket contains 29 child tickets, so I don't want to go ticket by ticket checking which files I've changed. I want to know which files I've played with since August 4th.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{2016-08-04}' --name-only
```